# Placing a link to PSD in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, file-format, import

When I place a PSD file from Photoshop to CC Illustrator the image gets embedded automatically.
I want it as a link not embedded image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Tick the **Link** option when using the Place command.

[image]